# Determine if the following composition function is onto

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-verification

Define $f: \Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$
and
$g: \Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}$
by:

$$f((a,b))=(a+b,2a)$$

$$g((c,d))=(c+2d,c)$$

Determine if $g \circ f$ is onto.

I figured out part one of this where it asks to determine if this function is one-to-one. So assume $(g \circ f)$$(a,b)$=$(g \circ f)$$(c,d)$, do some careful manipulation and back-substitution and in fact $a=c$, and $b=d$ so then $(a,b)=(c,d)$.

The follow up: how do I go about showing onto?

I had a different question that was just one polynomial function (just by itself and no $g$-function) where it made sense that for onto:

Every element of the codomain ($B$ let's call it) is the image ("mapping") of some element of (say $A$).  So, as I've come to understand this, we want to show that nothing in the co-domain is left "without a partner" from the domain.  Anyhow, I'm confused as to what I'll need to do this time where it's set up like this with cartesian-type mappings.  Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Notice that $g$ is not onto since, for example, there is no pair $(c,d)$ with $g((c,d))=(1,0)$.  Therefore $g\circ f$ cannot be onto.

Answer (score 1):

First, what is $g\circ f$? It is the function $$(a,b) \mapsto (5a+b,a+b).$$ Now is that onto? Take an arbitrary $(c,d)\in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. We must solve $c=5a+b$ and $d=a+b$. So $$b=d-a,\ \ \ \ c=5a+d-a=4a+d$$ and thus $c-d=4a$.

Since $(c,d)$ was arbitrary, there is no reason why $c-d$ should be divisible by $4$. So $g\circ f$ is not surjective.

Comment: how did you determine (5a+b,a+b)?  That's the big thing I'm not catching still I think

Comment: $f(a,b)=(a+b,2a)$ so $g(f(a,b))=g(a+b,2a)=(5a+b,a+b)$.

Comment: Ah that's why this looked all weird.  Ok... creating the "ordered pair" didn't come very quick to me where you have to keep track of which one gets "replaced" shall we say... yeah hard to explain that but I didn't figure out the "2d" part until I tried again on paper.  Now I got ya.

Comment: Understanding this kind of step-by-step, iterated substitution is very important not only in algebra, but also in writing software, if and when you get there.. Do get some more practice with such problems, it will be well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you probably have not had a linear algebra course; it would have made this problem much easier.

The matrix that expresses $f$ is
$$
F =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The matrix that expresses $g$ is
$$
G =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The matrix that expresses $g\circ f$ is
$$
GF =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now, both $F,G$ have determinant $-2,$ so $GF$ has determinant $4.$ It is only possible for a linear map taking an integer lattice to itself that has determinant $\pm 1$ to be surjective. All three matrices (and maps) discussed fail this. $f$ takes integer vectors to vectors with second coordinate even. $g$ takes integer vectors to vectors with first and second coordinates having the same parity. Finally, $gf$ takes integer vectors to vectors with first and second coordinates equivalent modulo 4.

Put another way,
$$
(GF)^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
-\frac{1}{4} &  \frac{5}{4}
\end{array}
\right)
$$
takes some points of the lattice to points not of the lattice, having rational entries.